# Pro Tools and sound design

Tags: pro-tools, sound-design, beginner

What are the basic functions one should know in pro tools when dealing with sound for a film?
Is elastic audio used a lot, or signal generator...... there are so many things to use. What is the most
Used plug ins and proccessors in pro tools. No outside plugins or processors please. I can not afford outside products yet. I'm currently running pro tools 8 m-powered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not so much a question of which tools are the most used, it's how and why they are used. For instance, the use of EQ and compression for film and video is different than it is for music production; the use of those tools is different even within the different disciplines of sound for picture (dialogue, effects, etc.). Get yourself some really in depth knowledge of how EQs, compressors, limiters and reverbs work (both practical hands on knowledge and the theory behind them), as that knowledge will transfer to any plug-in of those types...no matter who the manufacturer is. I always go back to the carpentry reference: just because you can swing a hammer doesn't mean you can frame a wall. But if you know how to properly frame a wall, you can probably do it with whatever tools someone hands you.

There's a whole level of technical knowledge that you'll want to develop as well; such as calibration, level standards, picture formats and their respective time codes, and general workflow integration in the larger process. There's a lot of knowledge that's needed to work in this field, and it's always changing.

I hope that didn't come off as discouraging, that's not my intention. I'm just trying to give you an idea of the work you have ahead of you. There's a lot of it (and it never really ends), but it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 3):

"dealing with sound for a film"

What aspects of sound for a film are you meaning?
If you are just starting out I wouldn't be worried about plugins so much - you need to learn to edit & sync sound first! Also bear in mind each of the people who deal with sound for film use ProTools differently:
- assistant dialogue editor
- dialogue editor
- ADR recordist
- sound effects editor
- foley recordist
- foley editor
- music editor
- sound designer

Have a look at the sound design book lists - theres lots to learn!